# Preserve Previous Data After Creating A New Instance Of An Object

Tags: .net, vb.net, variable-declaration, objectinstantiation

Say I have this:

```
Dim Editor As frmEditor
Editor.Text = "New Form"
Editor.Controls.Add(richTextBox)
```

Then later in a sub routine, I do this:

```
Editor = New frmEditor
```

Is it possible to save the controls/data of the previously declared `Editor` for future use? The one which was declared not the one which was instantiated using the `New` keyword.

Comment: Why not, just not use the same variable?

Comment: It doesn't work. If I'm not mistaken. `Editor = New frmEditor` creates a new object which is different from the previous one, removing all the controls and data? Please correct me if I'm wrong about this.

Comment: Hi there, could you do something like `Dim oldEditor as frmEditor` then before you do `Editor = New frmEditor` do `oldEditor = Editor`? `oldEditor` should then have a reference to the previous object

Comment: No problem - I've also moved the comment to the answer section in case anyone else has a similar question

Comment: Editor is reusing the same variable.  What part of NOT use the same variable was not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nkvu - moved from comments to answer in case anyone has a similar query....]

Could you do something like:

```
Dim oldEditor as frmEditor
```

Then before you do:

```
Editor = New frmEditor
```

Do this:

```
oldEditor = Editor
```

`oldEditor` should then have a reference to the previous object

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Editor As frmEditor
```

... does not create an editor, it declares only an empty variable, therefore ...

```
Dim Editor As frmEditor
Editor.Text = "New Form"
```

... will fail!

You **must** create a form with `New`:

```
Dim Editor As frmEditor
Editor = New frmEditor()
Editor.Text = "New Form"
```

Or

```
Dim Editor As frmEditor = New frmEditor()
Editor.Text = "New Form"
```

---

To answer your question:

Assign the "old" editor to another variable

```
Dim oldEditor As Editor = frmEditor
frmEditor = New frmEditor()
frmEditor.RtfText = oldEditor.RtfText
```

Also make a public property that allows you to access what you need to access from outside of the form

```
Public Property RtfText() As String
    Get
        Return richTextBox.Rtf
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        richTextBox.Rtf = value
    End Set
End Property
```